# Force LiveData Observer inside a Fragment to receive a change after coming visible again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am implementing `Android Architecture Components`. Imagine a case like the following where your `Fragment` is observing a `LiveData` to change its UI. User minimizes the app and the state is changed (in my case from the repository). So the `Observer` from the `Fragment` is not triggered with a change because the `Fragment` is not visible. But then, when the user comes back to the app it doesn't trigger the new state. If the state is changed again (while the `Fragment` is visible), the `Observer` receives the change. Do you know any way to force an update when fragment is visible again?

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    vm.getStatus()?.observe(this, Observer<MyRepository.Status> { status ->
        if (status != null) {
            when (status) {
                NONE -> setNoneUI()
                LOADING -> setLoadingUI()
                CONTENT -> setContentUI()
                ERROR -> setErrorUI()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: im facing smiliar issue while implementing MVVM, have you resolved this issue @Damia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your activity should receive the latest state from `LiveData` when it is visible again, as explained in this [video](https://youtu.be/bEKNi1JOrNs?t=12m59s) and described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html):

> Always up to date data: If a lifecycle becomes inactive, it receives the latest data upon becoming active again. For example, an activity that was in the
>   background receives the latest data right after it returns to the
>   foreground.

I just tested it in my own application, works as described. So there must be another error in your application: Do you set the `LiveData` correctly from your repository class? Maybe a different thread / `postValue` problem?